# SFMC Duplicate Contacts Query

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, contact, publicationlist, findduplicates

I am trying write a query that will result in duplicate SFMC contacts in a SFMC list.

More specifically, I have 3 brands and each has a shared publication list then there is the All subscriber List. Let's say I have a subscriber with the email address email@mail.com who is in the lists as follows.(note that each subscriberKey is unique)

EmailAddress         ListName        SubscriberKey
email@email.com      BrandA          0031500001dpVxEAAU
email@email.com      BrandA          0031500001dpVyjAAE
email@email.com      BrandA          0031500001dpVy7AAE
email@email.com      BrandB          0031500001dpVxUAAU
email@email.com      BrandC          0031500001dpVxNAAU
email@email.com      All Subscribers 0031500001dpVxNAAU

I need a query that can identify that this emailAddress exists on List BrandA 3 times and will give me all but 1 of those subscriber keys.

(The goal is that I will delete the results of the query from the contacts keeping only one contact per brand list or all subscriber list if they are not in any brand list)

Any suggestions?

This is an example of what does NOT give me what I need:

```
SELECT 
  EmailAddress
  , SubscriberKey
  , ListName
FROM _ListSubscribers 
WHERE EmailAddress IN (
    SELECT EmailAddress 
    FROM _ListSubscribers 
    GROUP BY EmailAddress 
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Row_Number() is one of the more useful functions for everything relating to deduping.

This will number your duplicates and from the result of the numbering, select all those that do not have the number 1, i.e. are duplicates.

Code is untested, but extrapolated from a working example. I hope it gives you a starting point.

```
SELECT a.EmailAddress,a.SubscriberKey
FROM (
  SELECT EmailAddress,SubscriberKey, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition by EmailAddress, ListName ORDER BY EmailAddress DESC) AS Row_Number   
  FROM _ListSubscribers) a
WHERE Row_Number != 1
```

Comment: Just a note, this would need to be Partitioned by EmailAddress and ListName (`Partition by EmailAddress, ListName`) in order to get the results he wants. Your example would return empty as SubscriberKey is a unique field and there can be no duplicates.

Comment: true, fixed this above. Thanks!

Comment: thank you, I"ll test this out now. great suggestions!

Comment: I just had to name the subquery so the where statement would not fail syntax and its running so let's see what it gives me!

Comment: also true. I edited in an alias "a" into the code. let us know

Comment: I would try to add a WHERE statement into the subquery:

WHERE Listname NOT IN ('A','B','C')

Comment: SELECT EmailAddress,SubscriberKey,ListName FROM (   SELECT EmailAddress   ,SubscriberKey   ,ListName   ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition by EmailAddress, ListName ORDER BY EmailAddress DESC) AS Row_Number      FROM _ListSubscribers) ls WHERE ls.Row_Number != 1 I'm getting closer!!! Now I just need to add a different list for garbage emails like no@no.com or ***@gmail.com etc.